# Cant get Streamlit and Postgresql to work together properly. Error with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, streamlit

After I enter all the private details into streamlit to connect to the Postgresql database, I cant seem to figure out how to get the Package Psycopg2 to import correctly on the Streamlit cloud.

When Streamlit tries to download the Psycopg2 package, the following error arises:

```
 × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.

  │ exit code: 1

  ╰─> [25 lines of output]

      /home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.

        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)

      running egg_info

      creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-b4u4zbek/psycopg2.egg-info

      writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-b4u4zbek/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO

      writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-b4u4zbek/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

      writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-b4u4zbek/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt

      writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-b4u4zbek/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

      

      Error: pg_config executable not found.

      

      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory

      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the

      option:

      

          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

      

      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

      

      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI

      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

      

      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at

      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).

      

      [end of output]
```

My problem is that I don't know how to add pg_config to the PATH. Here is my github: https://github.com/zuhorski/My-UFC-Project
Also for what its worth, I'm working in a virtual environment and I did find where this pg_config file is located: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin"

Comment: Did you read the error message, there 2 other ways shown how to provide the path to `pg_config` ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I did but im very new to this and am having trouble doing it. I tried a couple times with no success